# Запись в бинарный файл

Tags: c++, файлы

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Я записываю в файл записи, но я хочу сделать , так , чтобы когда пользователь вводил имя файла, и если в файле ничего нет, он бы выводил соответствующее сообщение о пустоте в этом файле.

Не могу понять в чем проблема в моем методе.

Если я создаю файл `2.bin`, например, но перед этим я ничего в него не записывал,то мой метод говорит, что я **имею одну запись**.

Код:

```
void City::readRecordings(char *fileName, char *num, std::vector<string> lines)
{

    string str;
    int readCount = 0;
    int n = atoi(num);

    long file_size;
    readRecord.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    file_size = readRecord.tellg();
    if (file_size == 0){
        std::cout << "File empty" << std::endl;
    readRecord.close();
      }
    if (_access(fileName, 0) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        readRecord.open(fileName);
        while (!readRecord.eof())
        {
            std::getline(readRecord, str);
            readCount++;
            lines.push_back(str);
        }

        if (0 == readCount)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: The file, which you are trying to open, is empty or it stops out" << END;
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (n > readCount)
        {
            std::cout << "!Warning!" << END;
            std::cout << "You want to read  " << n << " recordings" << " But AVAILABLE: " << readCount << " recordings" << END;
            printRecordsFromFile(readCount, lines);
        }
        else
        {
            printRecordsFromFile(n, lines);
        }
    }
}

void City::printRecordsFromFile(i num, std::vector<string> lines)
{
    for (i j = 0; j < num; j++)
        std::cout << lines[j] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это:

```
readRecord.eof()
```

сработает только **после** попытки чтения, а не до. Флаг конца файла устанавливается при неудачном чтении. Так что ваша проверка **до** ничего не дает...

Comment: а не подскажете , как сделать проверку **до** ?

Comment: Просто смотрите, что возвращает `getline`. Примерно так - `while (std::getline(readRecord, str))       {
            
            readCount++;
            lines.push_back(str);
        }`

Comment: спасибо за помощь! Получается, в этом `while()`,что он анализирует файл, и смотрит есть ли вообще что-то читать, а если как у меня было, то моя проверка не помогла, потому что он начал читать уже

Comment: Ну да, примерно так. Мой цикл простыми словами - "пока считывается, обрабатываем".

Comment: спасибо еще раз, помогли!